# Is it possible to display same content on different pages in wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I'm currently trying to display the same content on different pages on a WordPress site.

I do want to change certain words between that content that will be displayed on different pages?

is that possible in wordpress?

I feel like wordpress is very limited.

I just want suggestions from the community please! I'm as well googling my question, no luck yet. I'll keep posted.

Thank You.

Comment: The same content is a bit vague, but yeah a template, or a shortcode, or a sidebar widget can produce the same content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this and it makes a lot of sense now.

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/